# How to fit a paragraph element inside its parent container?

Tags: html, css

I'm having this problem:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<header class="fu-main-body-adress">
    <h3>Address</h3>
    <p><a href="#" target="_blank">hehehehehehehehehehhehehhehe</a></p>
</header>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: word-break: break-all / word-wrap: break-word; have you tried those rules ?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`word-break: break-all;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break).

> The word-break CSS property is used to specify whether to break lines within words.

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div>Loremipsumdolorsit.</div>
```

Or [`word-wrap: break-word;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)

> The word-wrap property is used to specify whether or not the browser may break lines within words in order to prevent overflow when an otherwise unbreakable string is too long to fit in its containing box.

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div a {
  word-wrap: break-word;  
}
```

```html
<div>
   <a href="">Loremipsumdolorsit.</a>
</div>
```

Comment: this is also a very good answer but I think the first one it is better for my case. Your answer it is very good as well and I'm going to use it for another case, so thanks :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You can try `text-overflow: ellipsis;` Learn more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow).

```css
p {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid aqua;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;                   
  overflow: hidden; /* "overflow" value must be different from "visible" */ 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="#">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754716/how-to-fit-a-paragraph-tag-inside-its-parent-container</a></p>
```